# Who are these two girls appearing in the OP of Shuffle?

Tags: shuffle

At around [1:10](https://youtu.be/9GQF1_PUTqE?t=71) in the opening of *Shuffle!*, there is a shot picturing two girls that seem to never appear in the anime.[image]

Who are they? What's their arc/story?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since I've played the original VN or watched the anime, but are these not Rin and Sia as imagined in their respective kingdoms? Matching features and both are princesses (kingdom of devils and kingdom of gods respectively) before coming to the human world.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Immediately after that shot, there are shots of the other three female characters.